# Count in jpa without getting result

Tags: jpa, count, criteria, named-query

I am trying to provide **all** my rest service responses (paged (partial) results) with total **count of records** in db, i.e. 1..5/150, I am using OpenJpa 2.3.0
I am getting my records in **two ways**, executing **namedQueries**, or building the query with **CriteriaBuilder**.

With criteriaBuilder, I am creating new criteriaQuery for `Long.class`, and then I provide predicates to both this and the original (the one that gets the records) Query

```
public static CriteriaQuery<Long> createCountCriteria(CriteriaBuilder cb, Class forType) {
    CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    countQuery.select(cb.countDistinct(countQuery.from(forType)));
    return countQuery;
}
```

that is working great. For named Query I tried to replace part of the query and execute it as nativeQuery

```
public static Query createCountQuery(EntityManager entityManager, Query query) {

    String queryStr = query.toString();
    int indexOfFromClause = queryStr.indexOf("FROM");

    if (!queryStr.isEmpty() && indexOfFromClause > -1) {
        return entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT count(1) " + queryStr.substring(indexOfFromClause));
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Query parameter is empty or invalid (no FROM clause found).");
}
```

But this is **only working while there is no where clause**, because in the where clause there is JPQL used, not the real db column names and therefore when executing, the exception with Unknown column raises up.

Could you show me any universal approach **without needing to provide xyzCount namedQuery as duplicate for each named query** as I dont like the idea to maintain everytime two queries? I tried to convert the named Query to native, so I could use my String replacement for "Select count(1)" but i dont know how to obtain the real SQL from query, or how to build criteriaQuery from named Query and then I could use it like when dealing with criteriaQuery.

Comment: finally I found the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285270/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-count-size-for-a-jpa-named-query-with-a-result-set so maybe this is a duplicate